# Clojure sprintf?

Tags: clojure, printf

There is printf. It prints directly to stdout.

How about sprintf, which formats the same way as printf, but returns a string with no side-effects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Clojure it's called [format](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/format) and resides in `clojure.core`: `printf` is equivalent to `(comp print format)`.

Answer (score 9):

You should check out `cl-format`, in the `clojure.pprint` lib.  It's a port of Common Lisp's [FORMAT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) function.  It can do things that Java's `printf` can't do, like conditionals, iterating over seqs, etc.

To answer your question, with `cl-format`, a first argument of `nil` will return a string; a first argument of `true` will print to STDOUT.

```
user> (cl-format nil "~{~R~^, ~}" [1 2 3 4])
"one, two, three, four"
```

Note that if `format` didn't already exist in Clojure, you could also capture the output from Clojure's `printf` like this:

```
user> (with-out-str (printf "%s" :foo))
":foo"
```

`with-out-str` is helpful when a library only provides a function that prints to STDOUT and you want to capture the output instead.  I've run across Java libraries that do this.

Comment: those java libs won't write to clojure's \*out\*, will they?  You'd need to hijack System/setOut with a PrintWriter that uses the var.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the with-out-str macro:

```
(with-out-str
    (print x))
```

Or just call java.lang.String's format method:

```
(String/format "%d" 3)
```

Comment: isn’t `(with-out-str (print x))` the same as `(str x)`? :)